# How can i find the total number of distinct arrays that can be obtained after applying given operation exactly k times?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given an array and elements inside the array are in range `[-10^6, 10^6]`.
We also have an integer `k`and we need to find how many different arrays can be obtained by applying an operation exactly `k` times. The only operation is to pick any element of the array and multiply it by `-1`.

For example, Array `A = {1, 2, 1}` and `k = 2`, different array obtained after `k` operations is `4` (`{1, 2, 1}`, `{-1, -2, 1}`, `{-1, 2, -1}`, `{1, -2,-1})`.

Although, Code and explanation are provided [here](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/82121/chefark-editorial) but it is hard to understand. Please someone simplify that explanation or give some other approach to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the size of the array be n. First see that the answer doesn't depend on the order of operations done.

Consider the two cases :

**Case 1 :** There are no zeros in the array and

**Case 2 :**  There are non-zero number of zeros in the array.

Considering **Case 1 :**

> **Sub-Case 1** : Number of elements >= number of operations i.e **n > k**
>
> Suppose we allow a maximum of 1 operation on every element, we can see that we can get <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k</sub> different arrays having **k** changed elements from the original array.
>
> But what happens when we do 2 operations on a single element ? The element basically doesn't change and keeping in mind that the order of operations doesn't change, you can put it this way : You took the initial array, selected an element, multiplied it by -1 twice and hence you are with the exact original array now but with just **k-2** operations in your hand which means that we are throwing away 2 of our k chances initially. Now we can carefully perform the **k-2** operations one on each element and get <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-2</sub> different arrays. Similarly you can throw away 4, 6, 8, .... chances and get <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-4</sub>, <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-6</sub>, <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-8</sub>, ..... arrays respectively for each case.
>
> This leads to <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-2</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-4</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-6</sub>+ <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-8</sub>+ ....... number of possible arrays if no element in the array is zero.
>
> **Sub Case 2** : **n < k**
>
> Since the number of operations are greater than number of elements you have to throw away some of your operations because you have to apply more than 1 operation on at least one element. So, if n and k both are even or both are odd you should throw k-n of your operations and have n operations left and from here it is just the sub case 1. If one is odd and one is even you have to throw away k-n+1 of your operations and have n-1 operations left and again it is just the sub case 1 from this point. You can try to get the expression for this case.

Considering **case 2 :**

> Notice that in the earlier case you were only able to throw away an even number of operations.
>
> Even here, there arise the cases **n >= k** and **n < k**.
>
> For **n >= k** case :
>
> Since there is at least one zero, you will now be able to throw away any number of operations by just applying that number of operations on any of the zeros since multiplying a zero with -1 doesn't affect it.
>
> So the answer here will simply be <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-1</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-2</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-3</sub>+ <sup>n</sup>c<sub>k-4</sub>+ .......
>
> And for **n < k** case :
>
> The answer would be <sup>n</sup>c<sub>n</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>n-1</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>n-2</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>n-3</sub>+ <sup>n</sup>c<sub>n-4</sub>+ ....... = 2<sup>n</sup>

I think this is a dynamic programming problem because you have to calculate the sum of <sup>n</sup>c<sub>r</sub>s. Logic wise it is a combinatorics problem.

Comment: thanks this is a much easy explanation to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's go throught the code, 
First there is this function nChoosek: it is a function that calculate the combination calculator, and this is what will be used to solve the problem 
Conbinaison is basically the number of selecting part of a collection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination 
 Example for array {1, 2, 3} if I tell you chose two item from the three item of the array this is Combination of tow from three, in the code it is nChoosek(2,3) = card{(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)} = 3 
If we consider the problem with those three additional conditions 
1- you can't multiply the same item twice 
2- n<=k 
3- there is no zero in the array 
The solution here will be nChoosek(k,n) but since those constraints exist we have to deal with each one of them 
For the first one we can multiply the same item twice: so for nChoosek(k,n) we should the number of array that we can have if we multiply an item (or many) twice by -1..
but wait let's consider the combinaition when we multiply a single item twice: here we lost two multiplication without changing the array so the number of combination that we have will be nChoosek(k -2 ,n)
The same way if we decide to multiply two item twice the result will be nChoosek(k -4 ,n)
From that comes

```
for(; i >= 0; i -= 2){
        ans += nChoosek(n, i);
        ans = ans % (1000000007l);

    }
```

For the case where k > n applying the algorithm imply that we will multiply at least one element twice so it is similar to applying the algorthm with k-2 and n
if k-2 still bigger than n we can by the same logic transform it to its equivalent with n and k-4 and so on until k-2*i <=n and k- 2 *(i+1) > 0
 It is obvious here that this k-2*i will be n or n-1 so the new k will be n or n-1 and this justify this code

```
   if(k <= n){
        i = k;
    }else if((k % 2 == 0 && n % 2 == 0) || (k % 2 != 0 && n % 2 != 0)){
        i = n;
    }else if((k % 2 == 0 && n % 2 != 0) || (k % 2 != 0 && n % 2 == 0)){
        i = n - 1;
    }
```

Now the story of zero, if we consider T1 = {1,2,3} and T2 ={0,1,0,0,2,3,0,0,0} and k =2 you can notice that the dealing with an array with length = n and has m zero is similar to dealing with array of length = n-m with no zero